# Why doesn't my subview fill the view in UIKit?

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

I'm doing a project in UIKit (XCode) for school: "Four In A Row" game.
I need to create a square grid in my view with custom items inside (1 vertical stack with N horizontal stacks containing N buttons).
So, the light blue square is a UIView I added to the superview, it's called "squareView".
I'm trying to insert a UIStackView programmatically to the squareView.
It works, almost, because I need the stack to fill the entire squareView and as you can see it doesn't take the entire accessible space.
How can I solve this?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the bounds change for a view controller's view, the view adjusts the positions of its subviews and then the system calls the [`viewDidLayoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews) method. So you need to set `StackView`'s frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` so you will get updated bounds of the `squareView` view. Now to do this you need a reference of `StackView`, so declare one optional property and initialise it `createGrid` function.

```
var verticalStack: UIStackView?

func createGrid(){
    let verticalStack = UIStackView()        
    verticalStack.frame = squareView.bounds
    verticalStack.backgroundColor=.systemRed
    verticalStack.axis = •horizontal
    verticalStack.distribution=.fillEqually
    verticalStack.spacing = 0
    squareView.addSubview(verticalStack)
    self.verticalStack = verticalStack //Set reference
}

//Set frame in viewDidLayoutSubviews
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.verticalStack?.frame = squareView.bounds
}
```

Comment: I'm not really good with Swift and Xcode, I'm sorry... so, you're saying I should create a new UIStackView class and override that method? or is it enough to write the same function as you did here?

Comment: I just copied it and works perfectly, thanks man <3